# Non domain data in repositories in Clean Architecture

Tags: clean-architecture

I'm wondering where should DTOs be put if repository interfaces are described in the domain layer which shouldn't ideally know about anything besides domain concepts, but i have to pass some information to/from these repositories that is actually an implementation details.

I'll give an example. Lets assume we have frontend app or perhaps backend querying external service/querying database, but obliged to get some technical data from there.

We describe a repository in lets say features/shop/domain/repositories.
I skip eithers and other stuff here.

```dart
abstract class ProductsRepository {
  Future<List<Product>> getProductsList(String category, int page);
}
```

And that's quite fine for now i suppose, despite "page" may not be much of domain concept.
Then if we need to pass some additional metadata to make successful request - we can add it to the actual request in implementation. But it's not always possible, sometimes there's no other way then passing some metadata through arguments.
And if we need to also provide some metadata from response - i don't see a way to do it without describing a DTO in domain layer. Like that:

```dart
abstract class ProductsRepository {
  Future<GetProductsListResponseDTO> getProductsList(String category, int page);
}

class GetProductsListResponseDTO {
  final List<Product> products;
  final bool isLastPage;
  final int timestamp;

  GetProductsListResponseDTO(this.products, this.hasMore);
}
```

Where isLastPage is for lazy loading and timestamp is for analytics for example.
Not the best as these functionalities could be implemented in other way, but it's just what came into my mind, lets assume we have strict requirements on that. In real applications there may be plenty of that kind of data, maybe even sticked to entities themselves like some metadata then used elsewhere for technical purposes/for ui only maybe.
And that would sort of break a definition of domain layer, the boundaries of it's knowledge.

Do you have any suggestions on what should be done in this case?

The general question is how to deal with data of non domain purpose that comes from external sources and should be passed to higher levels like application/view to deal with.

Comment: just to clarify, is your domain layer directly communicating with the external source for data?

Comment: No, in this hypothetical scenario i mean that application/ui layer must communicate with external source, not domain. And obtain some data from there that doesn't belong to domain, like some data for ui only.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, i've got some enlightment on that topic)
If someone's seeking for an answer, for adding metadata to models, i would do like that

```dart
// features/shop/data/models

class ProductMetadata {
  // whatever
}

class ProductModel extends Product {
  final ProductMetadata metadata;

  ProductModel(super.id, super.name, super.price, super.discount, super.imageUrl, this.metadata);
}

// features/shop/data/repositories
class ProductsRepositoryImpl implements ProductsRepository {
  @override
  Future<List<ProductModel>> getProductsList(String category, int page) {
    // TODO: implement getProductsList
    throw UnimplementedError();
  }
}
```

For the whole responses i think the same could be applied, but some response classes should be created in domain layer anyway to be then extended in data/infrastructure. Like

```dart
class ProductsListResponse {
  final List<Product> products;

  ProductsListResponse(this.products);
}

abstract class ProductsRepository {
  Future<ProductsListResponse> getProductsList(String category, int page);
}
```

Which may not be the best but a solution though, either way any ideas are still appreciated.